# SQL query optimization (time)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Consider a sample table 'salary_details'

[image].

Now, after some preprocessing, I have some Id's in my ArrayList ('user_id').

```
user_id(0): 1
user_id(1): 3
user_id(2): 4
user_id(3): 6
```

What, I would like to do is filter only those id's where salary = 2000.

Which approach is better:

```
1. 

   for (int i = 0; i < user_id.size(); i++) {
    SELECT ID FROM salary_details WHERE (part_id = user_id.get(i)) AND (SALARY = 2000)
    }
```

or

```
2. 

SELECT ID FROM salary_details 
   WHERE ((part_id = user_id.get(0)) 
     OR (part_id = user_id.get(1)) 
     OR (part_id = user_id.get(2)) 
     OR (part_id = user_id.get(3))) 
     AND (SALARY = 2000)
```

Or, are there other better options?

Comment: There's the `IN` operator which is specifically made for that.

Comment: Yes, thts also an option. What I was wondering is: is passing parameters within the loop a better option or not. What if after pre-processing i end up with more ids in my arraylist.

Comment: What the heck is this syntax:  `user_id.get(2)`?

Comment: @RickJames : W'll that was a dummy code.

Comment: I ended up using the 'IN' statement. I tried both methods, like **e4c5** and @DenysSéguret suggested. hitting database with an unnecessarily large number of queries was not optimal in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [IN](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) clause:

```
SELECT ID FROM salary_details WHERE SALARY = 2000 and part_id (in user_ids)
```

The exact syntax depends on your driver/language (just one thing: use a prepared statement, don't concatenate sql and values to build your query).

Now, the most efficient query

- must be found by measurement
- is very dependent of your data and indexes (use [`explain`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html))

Comment: Syntax:  `part_id IN (1,2,3)`.  Optimal index:  `INDEX(salary, part_id, id)`.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of those queries will run in it's current form!

As a rule of thumb, one avoids hitting the database with an unnecessarily large number of queries. Based on that criteria looping and querying from each id one by one is a big no-no

The second query is a lot better, but still it will be a big task to build it up if you have a large number of elements in your array.

The best approach is to use the [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) clause. This is a simple query, quite easy to build, easy for the query planner to parse and hits the database only once.

Having said, that when in doubt benchmark!